# Bootstrap Progress bar dots (bullet-point)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, progress-bar

I want to make a progress bar using Bootstrap that has some dots on that progress bar as in the image below. How can I do that? Or where exactly should I research?
[image]

```css
.progress {
  width: 278px;
  height: 7px;
  left: 597px;
  top: 489px;
}

.progress-bar {
  background: #007BFF;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="justify-content-center">
          <div class="progress" style="width: 100%">
            <div class="progress progress-bar" aria-valuenow="15%" aria-valuemin="0%" aria-valuemax="100%"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using range bars

[image]

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/forms/range/

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <label for="customRange1" class="form-label">Range bars</label>
    <input type="range" class="form-range" id="customRange1" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It won't work because I want to use that point at the beginning of the progress bar and at the end of the progress bar. I edited the question to be clearer.

Comment: Can you be more clearer, why exactly do you need this ( 2 dots on the start and end ) ?

Comment: There is no reason. The starting dot and the end dot are for design only.

Comment: So you just need a design, no particular functionality right?

Comment: Right. For the middle dot I need particular functionality, but for the 2 of the extreme parts I don't need.